# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Areas.Identity.Data...]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am getting the following error when I am trying to load my Identity login page -

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[FNSD.Areas.Identity.Data.FNSDUser]' while attempting to activate 'FNSD.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

My Program.cs is -

```
namespace FNSD.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Release"}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs is -

```
using FNSD.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FNSD.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
                options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;

                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(36500);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            });



            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                // Create accounts for the development environment
                //using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
                //{
                //    AccountsInitialiser.Initialize(scope.ServiceProvider);
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/PageNotFound");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/ExternalLogins", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Manage")));
                endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/TwoFactorAuthentication", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Manage")));
                endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/PersonalData", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Manage")));
                endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/ResendEmailConfirmation", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Manage")));

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("ContentRootPath", env.ContentRootPath);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("WebRootPath", env.WebRootPath);

        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationDBContext is

```
using FNSD.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FNSD.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<FNSDUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And FNSDUSer is -

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace FNSD.Areas.Identity.Data;

// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the FNSDUser class
public class FNSDUser : IdentityUser
{
    public FNSDUser()
    {

    }
    public FNSDUser(string userName) : base(userName)
    {
    }
}
```

And finally my FNSDContext is -

```
using FNSD.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FNSD.Data;

public class FNSDContext : IdentityDbContext<FNSDUser>
{
    public FNSDContext(DbContextOptions<FNSDContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

First time in trying Identity!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the exception message is pretty much clear, you don't have `SignInManager` descriptor in your services collection.

To fix that you need to add it like that:

```
services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<FNSDUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager(); // Here
```

Comment: Done that.  Still get the same error.

Comment: @KevBarri Ah I forgot to change parametrizer for `AddDefaultIdentity` call, it should be your user class, not just default `IdentityUser`

Comment: Arthur, if I change the AddDefaultIdentity call to my user class FNSDUser and run I don't even get to the Home page I get the following error - "InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered."

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Changed

```
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
        options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to

```
    services.AddIdentity<FNSDUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();
```

That solved my problem!